# Hide port in url when i use url::to() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing

Im newbie in Laravel. I wonder if it is possible to remove the port in the routing of Laravel, 
When I use this function `URL::TO()`.

I use NGINX & Varnish, The problem does not come from them. The URL `http://mydomain/users/login` works fine but when i use function `url::to()` function for generate URL, the port is automatically added in url.

Comment: Did you set the port in any config file ? I'd check `config/app.php` (and remove the port if you added it) because by default Laravel doesn't add the port unless you specified it somewhere in a config file.

Comment: No,there is no port in config file, my nginx running on alternative port : 8080

Comment: Does $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] contain the port? This might be the reason.

Comment: No, no port number in $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] :(

Comment: Ok Guys is my fault. I move fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT 80; in my nginx conf. it was before the include file that contains the parameters for Fast CGI